# Why List Box item not showing before ending the loop in c#?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have created a listbox where I am adding items inside a loop. But I am only able to see the item all together after the loop finishes. Whether it is a running application and it is adding some data to the DB which I need to show after adding each data.

Below is my code:

```
public void checkAutoRenewalWeekly(string keyword, string lang, int price, int provid2)
{        
    try
    {           
        //here I do something

        for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
           //Here I do something else and then add it to the list box

           logstr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Renew " + keyword + 
                    " : " + pmsisdn.Trim() + " ";

           // Here I am adding items but can only see after completing 
           // the whole functionality as this method is being called from 
           // another method so after completing that function
           // I can see the items all together
           this.lsLog.Items.Insert(0, logstr); 
           lsLog.Show();                    
        }

        ds.Clear();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logstr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + ex.Message;
        this.lsLog.Items.Insert(0, logstr);
        lsLog.Show();
        process_log(logstr, "err");
        logstr = ex.StackTrace;
        process_log(logstr, "err");
    }
}
```

Even I can't see the catch block writing also unless the method completes everything it is doing. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Please, provide small sample of code which reproduces your problem. Or at least remove code which is not related to issue

Comment: Is this a winforms app?

Comment: Use a background worker if you want to update the UI thread.

Comment: Yes I have checked that and it is having data even I tried with only three rows of data but still the same. I can only see it after finishing the loop.

Comment: Why are you using a bitwise OR inside your for loop? wouldn't it be simpler to write "if (dteDiff >= 7)"?

Comment: @EngJon thanks for your suggestion. I will re-write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsLog.Show()` doesn't do what you think it does, you need to release the UI thread for long enough to redraw the screen, which in a Windows Forms app, you can do by calling `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have just miified it a little bit. I have added this.Controls.Add(lsLog); to the for load event and then calling Application.DoEvents() after adding items with Listbox. And now it is working. Thanks a lot for your help.